# how can i split strings from Character Array

Tags: c, string, split, scanf

Here i have one character arrray in which there are some splitters are there.

character array is `char sentence []="abc_12.22.32.42";`

I want to read abc,12,22,32,42 from the sentence using sscanf.

I tried with sscanf but its given different output.

I posted here two code one of its working fine.

if i read `abc = 12` with `%s = %s` then its works. Why we have to give space between splitter.

Any way to achieve this goal.

**Not working Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="abc_12.22.32.42";
  char str [20];
  char str1 [20];
  char str2 [20];
  char str3 [20];
  sscanf (sentence,"%s_%s.%s.%s.%s",str,str1,str2,str3);
  printf ("%s --> %s --> %s --> %s --> %s\n",str,str1,str2,str3);
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
abc_12.22.32.42-->  -- � -->�Tl�s --> (null)
```

Expected Output :

```
 abc --> 12 --> 22 --> 32 --> 42
```

**working Code :**

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="abc = 12";
  char str [20];
  char str1 [20];
  char str2 [20];
  char str3 [20];
  if(sscanf(sentence,"%s = %s",str,str1) < 5) ;
        printf ("%s--> %s\n",str,str1);
  return 0;
}
```

output :

```
abc--> 12
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string with delimiters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying format like this: `%s_%s.%s.%s.%s`, your program can't know that first string can't contain characters `'_'` and `'.'`. That's the reason why `sscanf(sentence,"%s_%s.%s.%s.%s", str0, str1, str2, str3, str4);` causes whole sentence to be stored in `str0`.

If you want to stay with `sscanf`, you'll have to change the format that you expect:

```
char sentence[] = "abc_12.22.32.42";
char str0[20], str1[20], str2[20], str3[20], str4[20];
sscanf (sentence,"%19[^_]_%19[^.].%19[^.].%19[^.].%19[^.]",
        str0, str1, str2, str3, str4);
printf ("%s --> %s --> %s --> %s --> %s\n",
        str0, str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

`%19[^_]` causes `str0` to contain max 19 characters (20 with `'\0'`) and prevents character `'_'` to become part of `str0`. Thus the output becomes `abc --> 12 --> 22 --> 32 --> 42` as desired.

Alternatively you could use `strtok`.

Answer (score 1):

use `strtok` function. it's the best way to split strings

[strtok example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace ',' and '-' by ' ', also, you need one more array str4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char sentence []="abc_12.22.32.42";
    char str [20];
    char str1 [20];
    char str2 [20];
    char str3 [20];
    char str4 [20];

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(sentence); i++) {
        if (sentence[i] == '_') sentence[i] = ' ';
        if (sentence[i] == '.') sentence[i] = ' ';
    }

    sscanf (sentence,"%s %s %s %s %s",str,str1,str2,str3, str4);
    printf ("%s--> %s --> %s -->%s --> %s\n",str,str1,str2,str3, str4);
    return 0;
}
```