# How to parse a string with space int it to arrays?

Tags: c, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

I am writing a program in Linux to simulate Shell. The basic idea is first use fgets to get one line the user input, which is supposed to be something like `"ls -l"`, then I parse this string into "ls" and "-l" then construct a two dimensional array like `char *array[] = {"ls","-l"},`then use the `execvpe` which takes three arguments: the first is also from the input, that is "ls" in the example given above and the second would be array, the third would be a pointer like array in which I specify some directories.

The problem would be to parse string like "ls -l" into the two dimensional array. I intend to use `malloc` create the array. Parsing string in C seems quite unhandy.

Is there any good way to parse string like `"asd dg rg grhr"` into a array like `{"asd","dg","rg","grhr"}`.

Also any advice concerning simulating shell in another way is appreciated.

Comment: maybe, [strtok](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/) or [strsep](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/)?

Comment: @osgx cool, I never used or heard of them. Thanks~