# parent doesn't read from pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I want to communicate children process with parent process. I create 5 children and everyone send to pipe message "Hello". But parrent read only one message.. I'm very beginner and I don't know what I'm doing wrong... My code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n, p1[2], p2[2];
    n = 2*atoi(argv[1]);
    if(pipe(p1)) ERR("pipe1");
    if(pipe(p2)) ERR("pipe2");
    create_children(n, p1, p2);
        if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p1[1]))) ERR("close");
    parent_work(p1);
    if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p1[0]))) ERR("close");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void create_children(int number, int p1[2], int p2[2]) {
    while (number-- > 0) {
        switch (fork()) {
            case 0:
                if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p1[0]))) ERR("close");
                if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p2[0]))) ERR("close");
                child_work(p1[1], p2[1]);
                if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p1[1]))) ERR("close");
                if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(close(p2[1]))) ERR("close");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            case -1: ERR("Fork:");
        }
    }
}

void child_work(int fd, int fd1, char *name, int which) {
    char buffer[PIPE_BUF];
    size_t *len = (size_t*)buffer;

    char mb[PIPE_BUF];
    snprintf(mb,PIPE_BUF,"%d hello\n",getpid());
    if (-1 == TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY (write (fd, mb, (strlen(mb)+1))))  /
            ERR ("sending witaj");
            else
            printf("%s\n",mb);  
}

void parent_work(int fd) {
    char buffer[PIPE_BUF];
    if(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(read(fd, buffer, PIPE_BUF))==PIPE_BUF)ERR("read:");   
    printf("Process send message: %s\n", buffer);

    while(TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(wait(NULL))>0);
}
```

When I create 5 children, I received only 1 message.

Answer (score 1):

This can't work:

```
char mb[]=" ";
snprintf(mb,PIPE_BUF,"%d",getpid());
strcat(mb,"hello");
```

You write past the end of `mb` which has only room for two characters since it was initialized with a space followed by a NUL byte. In C, arrays don't magically grow when you write past their end, as you do with the `snprintf` and `strcat`.

Technically you invoke what is called **undefined behavior**, which means anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The children send null-terminated messages, so if the parent receives all messages in one `read` the parent will only print the first message.

I suggest that you let the children send newline-terminated messages instead (append a `\n` to the send string and don't send the null terminator).

Comment: If I make this way:
` char mb[PIPE_BUF];
    snprintf(mb,PIPE_BUF,"%d hello\n",getpid());`
It won't send null?

Comment: Do like that and use send length `strlen(mb)` (instead of `strlen(mb) + 1`).

Comment: I still don't get what I want.. Parent receives all messages in one like you said, but I need to write "Process send message: %s\n", buffer); for every child process separately :(

Comment: Split the read string on `\n`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c