# How do you modify a string splitting function to ignore consecutive delimiters?

Tags: c, string, split, delimiter

I am using a function that [was posted as an answer on another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c/9210560#9210560). The user who posted this however notes that: `it does not handle consecutive delimiters`.

I am wondering how I can modify this so that it could handle consecutive delimiters? I want to essentially ignore it when I have an extra delminator.

For example say I have something like this:

`h2,3       d3,4 j3,3 y4,1     g4,3`

I want to split this into an array of strings at each space, however as you can see in some cases there are multiple spaces. I simply want to ignore the extra delimiters.

Edit: Just to make it clear this is the code I am using from the answer I linked to above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char months[] = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC";
    char** tokens;

    printf("months=[%s]\n\n", months);

    tokens = str_split(months, ',');

    if (tokens)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
        {
            printf("month=[%s]\n", *(tokens + i));
            free(*(tokens + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(tokens);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring may not be the correct approach depending on the case. Two delimiters in sequence only mean there's an empty string between them.

Comment: @Havenard That's where `strsep()` differs? Use the appropriate function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
char** str_split(const char *str, char delimiter)
{
    int len, i, j;
    char* buf;
    char** ret;

    len = strlen(str);
    buf = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(buf, str, len + 1);

    j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (buf[i] == delimiter)
        {
            while (buf[i + 1] == delimiter) i++;
            j++;
        }

    ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (j + 1));
    ret[j] = NULL;

    ret[0] = buf;
    j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (buf[i] == delimiter)
        {
            buf[i] = '\0';
            while (buf[i + 1] == delimiter) i++;
            ret[j++] = &buf[i + 1];
        }
    return ret;
}
```

Drop the two lines `while (buf[i + 1] == delimiter) i++;` if you want it to disable sequenced delimiters overruning.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `const` on the input string?

Comment: @Fogest It means this function can be used with string literals. It won't modify the buffer you provide.

Answer (score 1):

The heavily voted answer in your SO question says *note it does not handle consecutive delimiters, "JAN,,,FEB,MAR"* - but does not substantiate the contributor's comment.

The function `strsep()` treats consecutive delimiters as containing an empty field, but the function `strtok()` **does** ignore multiple instances of (any combination of) the delimiter set. With MSVC, I get for this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char months[]= "JAN, ,\t   , ,FEB,MAR";
    char seps[] = ", \t\r\n";
    char *sptr;
    sptr = strtok(months, seps);
    while (sptr) {
        printf ("Month is: %s\n", sptr);
        sptr = strtok(NULL, seps);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
Month is: JAN
Month is: FEB
Month is: MAR
```

In your specific example (which I suspect might contain tabs), this would be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char stuff[]= "h2,3      d3,4 j3,3 y4,1 g4,3";
    char seps[] = " \t";
    char *sptr;
    sptr = strtok(stuff, seps);
    while (sptr) {
        printf ("Stuff is: %s\n", sptr);
        sptr = strtok(NULL, seps);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
Stuff is: h2,3
Stuff is: d3,4
Stuff is: j3,3
Stuff is: y4,1
Stuff is: g4,3
```

Comment: So you're saying I should use this code instead? Because I am trying to store each element into an array. Using the example line of data I provided I should get an array looking like: `["h2,3", "d3,4", "j3,3", "y4,1", "g4,3"]`

Comment: Added your specific example.

Comment: sorry, forgot to Post it duh.

Answer (score 0):

I think `strtok()` is capable of handling your requirement. From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter.

Comment: Did you look at the code I am actually using? Because it is already using strtok....