# Array of "strings" in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I know that there is a question with the same name, but it didn't work for me.
I'm making a home-compiler, returns the words that belongs to a language.

The words to analyze are in this vector:

```
char *cadenas[]= {"123", "4567L", "5a23", '\0'};
```

Now I want to enter the words by console, but strings can't be used in C, how can I do it? (Without making a matrix possibly)

```
void getCadenas(char *cadenas[]){

    printf("Enter cadenas to be analyzed ('z' to scape) \n \n");

    char cadena[15];
    gets(cadena);
    int x=0;

    while(cadena[0]!='z'){
        strcpy(cadenas[x],cadena);
        x++;
        gets(cadena);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `cadenas` is basically is _sort-of_ a matrix already (array of an array). So what is the question?

Comment: Strings can't be used? Strings can be used. Question could do with a tidy-up, unclear what you want.

Comment: Did you look at [Taking user input and storing it in an array of strings in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30428615/3466415)? Does it solve your problem? If not, why not?

Comment: `strcpy(cadenas[x],cadena);` : Rewriting of the string literal is not allowed. (Also it does not have enough space.)

Comment: also, you probably want to use `strncopy(destination, src, length)` to make sure you don't walk off the location you're copying to...

Comment: Do you want to know how to correctly read a string in C?

Comment: Note: I'd expect `{"123", "4567L", "5a23", NULL}` rather than `{"123", "4567L", "5a23", '\0'}`

Comment: @chux i think he probably is looking for a null terminated empty string as the last entry in his array of strings, which isn't NULL

Comment: never **ever** use `gets()`, it's [broken](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html#BUGS)

Comment: @Neil: it's an array of pointers, `NULL` is appropriate, `'\0'` is not

Comment: @Veltas hmm I didn't say he had it correct - but I would not be passing NULL into strcpy without first checking as this is going to lead to an exception..

Comment: Yeah my bad, should be `"\0"` rather than `'\0'`.

Comment: @Veltas Or simply `""`.

Comment: Yes `""` is exactly what you should use.

Comment: Is `cadenas` spanish for 'strings'?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would like the user to be able to enter multiple strings, until he/she types `z`

See if this piece of code helps you out. The strings will be stored in the `cadenas` array, as requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define MAX_CADENAS 100
#define MAX_CADENA_LEN 255
int getCadenas(char **cadenas){
    int x=0;
    char cad[MAX_CADENA_LEN+1];
    printf("Enter cadenas to be analyzed ('z' to scape) \n \n");

    while(x<MAX_CADENAS) {
        scanf("%s", cad);
        if (strcmp(cad,"z")==0)
            break;
        cadenas[x] = malloc(strlen(cad)+1);
        strcpy(cadenas[x], cad);
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

char *cadenas[MAX_CADENAS];
int main() {
    int num, i;

    num = getCadenas(cadenas);
    for (i=0;i<num; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", cadenas[i]);
    }
}
```

Note0: the code assumes you know in advance what the maximum number of input strings can be (100). It also assumes a maximum size for each input string (255 characters)

Note1: `gets` is deprecated. Also, instead of `scanf`, you might want to use `fgets`.

Note2: the present code is for illustrative purpose only. It allocates memory for each input string, but it assumes no error occurs in doing so (i.e. it does not check what `malloc` returns).

Note3: the allocated memory blocks must be freed when not used anymore (hint: cycle through the `cadenas` array and use `free`)

Comment: You should probably just change your answer to use fgets, given that it's not hard to use and is about as long as a scanf call anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind carrying on with fixed-size strings and arrays, here is your original program modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CADENAS 100
#define CADENA_LIMIT 1000

// ...

void getCadenas(char cadenas[MAX_CADENAS][CADENA_LIMIT]){

    printf("Enter cadenas to be analyzed ('z' to scape) \n \n");

    int x;
    for(x=0; x<MAX_CADENAS-1; x++){
        char cadena[CADENA_LIMIT];
        fgets(cadena, CADENA_LIMIT, stdin);
        // fgets will copy the newline character, we don't want that
        int cadenaLength=strlen(cadena);
        if(cadena[cadenaLength-1]=='\n')
            cadena[cadenaLength-1]='\0';
        if(strcmp(cadena, "z")==0) break;
        strcpy(cadenas[x], cadena);
    }
    cadenas[x][0]='\0';
}

// ...
```

Prefer `fgets` as you can prevent overflow of the fixed-size strings. Unfortunately it copies the newline as well, so I have code to handle that. The result is an array in the form you originally specified (except it ends with `""` which we decided was what you were after in the comments).

You *can* read arbitrary sized strings in C like in other languages, but you would need to implement it with [`malloc()` and co](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html). Allocating dynamically sized memory is primarily controlled with the functions `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and `free`. **This would make the program unavoidably more complicated**. Here is one way of doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ...

char *getCadena(){
    int length=0, capacity=1, character;
    char *cadena=malloc(1); // sizeof(char) is always 1
    while((character=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(character=='\n') break;
        // Add character to string
        length++;
        if(capacity<length){
            capacity*=2;
            cadena=realloc(cadena,capacity);
        }
        cadena[length-1]=character;
    }

    // Add terminator to cadena
    length++;
    if(capacity<length){
        capacity*=2;
        cadena=realloc(cadena,capacity);
    }
    cadena[length-1]='\0';

    return cadena;
}

char **getCadenas(){

    printf("Enter cadenas to be analyzed ('z' to scape) \n \n");

    int length=0, capacity=1;
    char **cadenas=malloc(sizeof(char *));
    for(;;){
        char *cadena=getCadena();
        if(strcmp(cadena,"z")==0){
            free(cadena);
            break;
        }
        // Add pointer to cadenas array
        length++;
        if(capacity<length){
            capacity*=2;
            cadenas=realloc(cadenas,capacity*sizeof(char *));
        }
        cadenas[length-1]=cadena;
    }

    // Add NULL to end of cadenas
    length++;
    if(capacity<length){
        capacity*=2;
        cadenas=realloc(cadenas,capacity*sizeof(char *));
    }
    cadenas[length-1]=NULL;

    return cadenas;
}

void freeCadenas(char **cadenas){
    int i=0;
    while(cadenas[i]!=NULL){
        free(cadenas[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(cadenas);
}

// ...
```

This works mostly the same as the previous function, except you should use `freeCadenas` eventually, and I end the array with `NULL` instead of `""` which is customary.

The code is a lot longer, but it's pretty typical of more sophisticated C code with less arbitrary limits. In fact real C code usually has more robust handling of errors and more generic functions for managing dynamic arrays. If you actually manage to make this "home-compiler", however, you will figure all this out for yourself.