# Convert a comma separated string to an array in proc

Tags: c, string, split

I need to convert a comma separated string to an array in proc, I am getting the string in:

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "do:c")) != EOF)
{
    switch (ch) 
    {
        case 'c':
            get_order_type(optarg);
```

`get_order_type(optarg)` is comma separated string like `30,31,32` I need to get each string.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is strtok. That means String Tokenizer.

I think this will work for you:

```
  char str[] = get_order_type(optarg);
   const char s[2] = ",";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
```

Anyway, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) you have the documentation for the method.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Should not it be: const char s[1] = ",";

Answer (score 0):

```
#define max_strln 30
```

#define  max_str_no 20

```
char input[] = get_order_type(optarg);
char *str;
int i_ctr;
char arr[max_str_no ][max_strln];    

for(i_ctr = 0,str = strtok(input,","); str!= NULL; i_ctr++, str= strtok(NULL,","))
  {
    strcpy( arr[i_ctr], str);
  }
```

### Explanation:

we take comma separator string in "input" variable and tokenize that variable by delimiter ( here comma).
strtok return string which is separate by delimiter (here comma is delimiter).
finally we copy that string into array using copy function.

Comment: copy "get_order_type(optarg)" in str_wth_comma variable

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Yes its ans of given question. strtok return string which is separated by delimiter (here comma is the delimiter).

Comment: @TobySpeight : if u satisfied with ans plz accept it

Comment: It is probably best to post something you've at least compiled - there's too many errors in the above to make a good answer.