# Splitting a string into words

Tags: c

I have following problem:

```
// Basically I am reading from a file and storing in local array.

char myText[100] = "This is text of movie Jurassic Park";

// here I want to store each work in to dictionary

st.insert(&myText[0]); // should insert "This" not till end of sentence.

// similarly for next word "is", "text" and so on.
```

How do I do that in C?

Comment: With 2878 rep you should be able to find out by yourself. Downvote is not from me.

Comment: Is `insert` a pointer to a function in a `struct` of which `st` is an instance?

Comment: 1. Define "word" (either in terms of Consisting-Of or Consisting-Not-Of). 2. Loop over your input until you get to the start of a word. 3. Loop over your input until you come to the end of a word. 4. ... profit!

Comment: Look for examples using `strtok` or `strtok_r`.

Comment: This question is not at all clear.  Are you saying you want to convert your C++ code to just C?  And what is your comment saying about "should insert not"?  Please rephrase that  to express what it is you want.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Without taking any sides, let me just point out that the gained reputation doesn't have to be related to knowledge of a particular programming language. StackOverflow covers many areas.

Comment: @Tlacenka you are right, but someone with rep should be able to to do basic google searches, for example "Splitting a string into words c".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string with delimiters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

For this, you would use the [`strtok` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok):

```
char myText[100] = "This is text of movie Jurassic Park";
char *p;
for (p = strtok(myText," "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL," ")) {
    st.insert(p);
}
```

Note that this function modifies the string it's parsing by adding NUL bytes where the delimiters are.

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtok().  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

For C you will need to include .

Comment: It's best to give an example instead of just pointing to a url.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split on spaces, you basically may want an `strsplit` or `strtok`.
Have a look at [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)