# Taking input from 2 lines and store it into array

Tags: c

I want to take input as

```
9.30 9.45 14 16

11 14 15 16      // in two separate lines
```

The size of the array is not given. I want to take these input from keyboard and put into two separate arrays and then perform some operations.

Note: Input is of two lines only and if we press enter after first line, then it should go to next line and then terminate.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Please show what you have tried, or what *specific* problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in function strtok() to split a given string into tokens might be what you need. Check here: [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

EDIT: Apparentely, strtok has been deprecated: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/