# Easiest way to parse colon delimited paths

Tags: c

I have a program that uses an environment variable to get a list of paths, like $PATH. I would like to know the easiest way to parse out the individual paths from this environment variable.

Comment: use strtok() function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c