# Array separation --- C

Tags: c, arrays

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 100
int main (){

    char rest[DIM];
    scanf ("%s", rest);
    char first;
    first = rest[0];
```

The input the user will put will either be something like `"1 dsdsff e"` or `"2 dej deer"`. How can I save the different words in `rest` that will be separated by `" "`? And disregard the first number since I've already stored it.

Comment: read it using `fgets()` and use `strtok()` to tokenize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scanf with formatted template

```
int n;
char rest1[DIM], rest2[DIM];

scanf("%d %s %s", &n, rest1, rest2);
```

In that case input `'42 text1 text2'` will gave `n == 42`, rest1 will contain 'text1' and rest2 will contain 'text2'

Comment: the thing is that rest1 will be " text1" and I do not want the space at the begining

Comment: @Aen: `%s` reads a whitespace delimited string, so no spaces will ever be stored in `rest1` or `rest2`.  Note that the space before `%s` is irrelevant -- spaces will be skipped regardless.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yeah, you're right. I was doing something wrong. Anyway, this is a good solution except that sometimes the input is simply "1" (which I forgot to mention)

Comment: @Aen In case when you dont know actual number of parameters you should read whole string and parse them one-by-one

Comment: @LibertyPaul how? I've tried strtok but since I want to save them it's not working right

Answer (score -1):

You are storing the string in an array that's correct, then you have to split that array by delimiter ' '. Here is the code that might help you.

[Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. If you found a duplicate, flag the question.