# Find the number with maximum digits in it

Tags: c, file, floating-point, numbers

This was an exam question a few years ago, and I am struggling to solve it.

I have to build a program that reads from a text file a set of number, with a space in between, that could either be integers or floats. Then it prints the number with  the maximum number of digits in it using a recursive function.

I don't know how to read the numbers from the file. If I read them all like floats they end up with the same amount of digits. Here's my code until know, but I don't know how to proceed. 
For example:

*In the text file we have the numbers:* **1  2  1.5  1.456  2  2.78  7**

*The number with the maximum number of digits is* **1.456** *with* **4** *digits in it.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int n,i,nr=0;
    float v[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("text.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp,"%f",&v[nr])==1){
        nr++;
    }
    fclose(fp);



    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: you should check fp `if (fp==NULL){ /* error */ }`

Comment: @Michi I always do that but it is not my problem now

Comment: Can you give a better example? Example input and output?

Comment: Then show us a possible content of that file and an input/output like @Tyler said

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Read one character at a time with `fgetc`. There are five possibilities: digit, dot, space, newline, or other.

Comment: From @Tyler's comment, emphasis on **output** (and possibly something about how your recursive function works as it seems to not work on all floats).

Comment: why make things complicated.  Have float variable `maxDigits` set it to `0.0f` read each successive number, into a temporary float value.  Compare the just read (temporary) float value with the value in `maxDigits`  if maxDigits is less than temporary float value, then assign maxDigits = temporary'.   Loop until EOF encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat the input as a simple string, you should be able to just `strlen()`, no?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    size_t maxdigits = 0, i;
    char buf[128], winner[128];
    char winner[128];
    FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("missing text.txt\n");
       return -1;
       }
    memset(winner, 0, sizeof(winner));
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", buf) == 1) {
        i = strlen(buf);
        if (strchr(buf, '.') != NULL)
            i--;
        if (i > maxdigits) {
            maxdigits = i;
            strcpy(winner, buf);
            }
        }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("winner '%s' has %d digits\n", winner, maxdigits);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It should ignore decimals.

Comment: `int i` should be `size_t i` because of the return type of `strlen`, but even if you fix it you still have comparison problem with maxdigits which is an int

Comment: and `maxdigits` too ...followed up with `%zu` format specifier.

Comment: by the way, when you fix that...you end with a segfault

Comment: I appreciate the various tweaks -- but I really was hoping to "lead" the OP to finished product -- NOT create it myself. The version above compiles & works on his sample input set using `gcc 4.4.7`. Enhancements should be up to OP.

Comment: I meant this part [CLICK](http://pastebin.com/raw/4N0aEn9z) where the check of *fp is not present.

Comment: Did you create 'text.txt' before running valgrind? Program has no error checking (so OP can focus on the core of the program).  Obviously production code would need to check `fopen` succeeded AND make sure `fscanf` did not exceed size of `buf`. Also, program does not explicitly close `fp`.  All exercises for OP.

Comment: @user590028 You are missing the whole point here, and yes I used [This](http://ideone.com/N7bS6j) and valgrind says [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/KiPXE0N0)

Comment: @Michi well what *is* your point? Tell us the error in your own linked code for heaven sake. Apart from not initialising `winner`.

Comment: I think valgrind is warning you about memory leak no? That would likely be because `fp` was not closed.

Comment: I surrender -- all fixes applied.

Comment: @user590028 Thanks man! Only the idea of treating the input as a string would be fine, but you even provided the code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use the "split" function.

Seems like here is something for you
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)