# Separating a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

so I need help separating one string into multiple separate ones.
For example, let's say I have something like:

```
char sentence[]= "This is a sentence.";
```

and I want to split it to:

```
char A[]="This";
char B[]="is";
char C[]="a";
char D[]="sentence.";
```

Comment: look into `strtok()`

Comment: You may need to use strdup too. (You can't strtok a constant)

Comment: `sentence` isn't a constant -- it is just initialized.

Comment: @JohnColeman Likely he wants to say that copying might be necessary for leaving the source string untouched ("may need"). +1 to both, :-)

Comment: On what basis you want to separate the string?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Good point. People coming to C from other languages are likely to be tripped up by the destructive nature of `strtok` the first time they encounter it.

Comment: Yes, it is a trap and I should add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can use `strtok()` to do this job. The usage is not very intuitive:

```
char sentence[]= "This is a sentence."; // sentence is changed during tokenization. If you want to keep the original data, copy it.

char *word = strtok( sentence, " ." ); // Only space + full stop for having a multi delimiter example
while (word!=NULL)
{
  // word points to the first part. The end of the word is marked with \0 in the original string
  // Do something with it, process it, store it
  … 
 word = strtok( NULL, " ."); // To get the next word out of sentence, pass NULL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same question, different split requirement:

> [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)