# C program - how can I read characters part by part from a string

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  

void main()   
{

char source[30]="salai word2 word3";   
char destination[20][20];   

printf(" \n\source is: %s\n\n", source);   
getch();  
}
```

In the above program, char variable "source" contains three words(separated by space). How can I read the words from "source" and store in another char array "destination". Expectation as follows:

```
strcpy(destination[0], salai)   
strcpy(destination[1], word2)  
strcpy(destination[2], word3)
```

Comment: and `strtok()`, maybe

Comment: This "how" is too broad, VTC. Also, show your efforts till time.,

Comment: See this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c

Comment: @SouravGhosh, Thank you. strtok() function full fill the need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop. Insert the characters until you get a space. You can try this.

```
int i,j=0;
int len = strlen(source);
int k=0;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(source[i] == ' ')
        { 
          k++;
          j=0;
        }
    else
      destination[k][j++]=source[i];
   }
```