# Parsing a string with scanf

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I need to get integers from a string that an user enters into the console.

For exemple:
I have this string: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and I would like to get all of the integers from it. I already tried multiple `scanf` patterns, such as `scanf("%*[^\[]%d,", &a)`, but nothing worked. I couldn't find anything relevant on Stack Overflow either.

The main problem is that he can enters between 1 and 50 integers into his string. I have no idea about how to stock only integers (removing ',' and '[' ']' ) into an array.

Some solutions have been found for removing special chars such as [ ] or ,
But now I still need to remove SPACE between comas and integers...

EDIT : problem solved using fgets. I was using scanf to get my string, but it were stopping to SPACES.

Fond out how to do that with scanf :

while(scanf(" %d",&i))

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c

Comment: Be more specific. is it a string (i.e. an array of chars) or an array of integers? (since you are stating you want to get integers from it).
I am going to assume you mean an array of chars, then you can access each element if a loop like this: for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char); ++i) arr[i] = //do something

Comment: I voted to close, since the question is unclear, and essentially asking for help getting code working which is not shown.   `scanf()` is not used to read from strings at all, so no "patterns" will work. `sscanf()` [note the double `s`] might be used for that purpose.

Comment: It is a string of chars, that's something user have to enter into the console, I need to get integers from the string. He gives me something like [1,50,60], I need to stock only the integers somewhere.

Comment: Advice: don't parse with `scanf` and friends, period. You can use `scanf` only if the input is predetermined.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and a clear description why each attempt is insufficient.  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code, by using `strtok` you can separate out all type of unwanted characters in your string. Add all your unwanted set of character to this `s` array and let `strtok` do the work.

```
char str[]="[1,2,3,4,5]";
const char s[4] = "[],"; // All unwanted characters to be filtered out
char *token;
token = strtok(str, s);
while( token != NULL ) 
{
  printf( "%d\n", atoi(token));
  token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

Since you have it in the integer format, you could store it in an array and go further with it.

Output :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: It works perfectly well thanks a lot! But I still have a little problem : I need to put spaces into the string (ex : [1, 2, 3] and I can't set the "SPACE" char into unwanted chars... Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I tried to add octal code '\040' into the const char s[5] = "[],'\040'"; but it looks like GCC doesn't understand what I want to do.

Comment: @Nofix Even if there is space in your string, the tokeniser works just fine, Check this out, i added space in the string and the code just works fine by printing out only integers https://ideone.com/edSfup

Comment: @Nofix Did you check it out?

Answer (score 2):

`scanf`/`sscanf` does not support regular expressions. You should try something like:

```
const char my_string[] = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
int a,b,c,d,e;
sscanf(my_string, "[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/AOaD7x

It can also be good to check the return value of `scanf`/`sscanf`:

```
int retval = sscanf(my_string, "[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d]", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);
if (retval != 5)
    fprintf(stderr, "could not parse all integers\n");
```

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

**Edit:**
In your edited question you asks how to do this if there is a variable number of integers. You can use `strchr` to locate the next comma in the string and continue to iterate until no more comma is found. This assumes that the string ends with `]`.

```
const char my_string[] = "[1,2,3,4,5]";

/* start at first integer */
const char *curr = &my_string[1];

while (curr != NULL) {
    /* scan and print the integer at curr */
    int tmp;
    sscanf(curr, "%d", &tmp);
    printf("%d\n", tmp);

    /* find next comma */
    curr = strchr(curr, ',');

    /* if a comma was found, go to next integer */
    if (curr)
        /* warning: this assumes that the string ends with ']' */
        curr += 1;
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/RZkjWN

Comment: Okey thanks, but my main problem is that I have no idea how many numbers can be into the string. I mean : there wont be more then 50 numbers, but I the number of integers in the string isn't a const.

Comment: Iterate and call sscanf (with an offset)  until it returns zero.

Comment: I don't get it : how can you do itterations with a sscanf with a const string. I mean : the string will never change for each interration, so it will be endless right? I just tried to itterate with scanf("%c%d", &test, &tab[0]); and scanf never ends...

Comment: Why not use `sscanf(my_string, "[%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);`  (no  `]`)?  Using it gives the false impression that the input string is somehow tested for the presence of `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf()` for parsing strings is not recommended.

Similarly to others answers, you can use [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse the numbers between `"[],"`, and convert the found numbers using [`strtol`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm). It would be dangerous to use something like `atoi()` for integer conversion, as their is no error checking with it. Some more error checking with `strtol()` can be found in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Here is some sample(can be improved) code which does this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNUM 50
#define BASE 10

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
    char *number, *endptr;
    const char *delim = "[],";
    int numbers[MAXNUM], current;
    size_t i, count = 0;

    number = strtok(string, delim);
    while (number != NULL) {
        current = strtol(number, &endptr, BASE);

        /* checking if valid digit found */
        /* more error checking can be added */
        if (endptr != number) {
            numbers[count++] = current;
        }
        number = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("numbers[%zu] = %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input 1:

```
string[] = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
```

Output 1:

```
numbers[0] = 1
numbers[1] = 2
numbers[2] = 3
numbers[3] = 4
numbers[4] = 5
```

Sample input 2:

```
string[] = "[1,a,3,c,5]";
```

Output 2:

```
numbers[0] = 1
numbers[1] = 3
numbers[2] = 5
```