# C - Splitting into substrings

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can i split a string into 2 strings ?

**Example** `Char[100]= "Xo = 100K"`
i want to split it to 2 string and save them into > Xo & 100K.

I could only save the first string, but i couldn't save the other one.

My code :-

```
while (ch[i]!= '=')
i++;
strncpy(var,ch,i);
```

Comment: For example using `strtok`. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c) (but there are many others):

Comment: `char var[100], value[100]; if(2 == sscanf(ch, "%s = %s", var, value)){ /* do stuff */}`

Answer (score 0):

By using `strtok` function you are able to setup string of delimiters to function to create chunks from string.

By using `" ="` as delimiter you will get your result.

Comment: i know i can use "strtok" but how can i save the substrings as a variable is that what i aim for ^_^ can you help me please?