# C string nested splitting

Tags: c, string, split

I'm a beginner at C and I'm stuck on a simple problem. Here it goes:
I have a string formatted like this:  "first1:second1\nsecond2\nfirst3:second3" ... and so on.
As you can see from the the example the first field is optional ([firstx:]secondx).
I need to get a resulting string which contains only the second field. Like this: "second1\nsecond2\nsecond3".

I did some research here on stack ([string splitting in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)) and I found that there are two main functions in C for string splitting: **strtok** (obsolete) and **strsep**.
I tried to write the code using both functions (plus **strdup**) without success. Most of  the time I get some unpredictable result.

Better ideas?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
This was my first try

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char * stri = "ciao:come\nva\nquialla:grande\n";
    char * strcopy = strdup(stri); // since strsep and strtok both modify the input string
    char * token;
    while((token = strsep(&strcopy, "\n"))){
        if(token[0] != '\0'){ // I don't want the last match of '\n'
            char * sub_copy = strdup(token);
            char * sub_token = strtok(sub_copy, ":");
            sub_token = strtok(NULL, ":");
            if(sub_token[0] != '\0'){
                printf("%s\n", sub_token);
            }
        }
        free(sub_copy);
    }
    free(strcopy);
}
```

**Expected output:** "come", "si", "grande"

Comment: Show us your code.  `strtok()` is not obsolete!

Comment: @JohnZwinck It should be :p, `strtok_r()` is far better.

Comment: @Stargateur: Better yet: `strspn()` / `strcspn()`.

Comment: when the parameters to the `main()` function are not used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: when calling `strdup()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the posted code, even after adding statements for: 'stdio.h', 'stdlib.h' and 'string.h' does not compile.  One reason is this statement: `free(sub_copy);` as the pointer: `sub_copy` is only visible with the scope of the code block: `if(token[0] != '\0')`

Comment: regarding: `while((token = strsep(&strcopy, "\n"))){`  before searching for a newline, should be checking for an (optional) 'xxx:' sequence

Comment: regarding: `if(sub_token[0] != '\0')`  the first char will NEVER be '\0'.  However, the contents of `sub_token` could be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `strcspn`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "ciao:come\nva\nquialla:grande\n";
    const char *p = str;
    while (*p) {
        size_t n = strcspn(p, ":\n");
        if (p[n] == ':') {
            p += n + 1;
            n = strcspn(p , "\n");
        }
        if (p[n] == '\n') {
            n++;
        }
        fwrite(p, 1, n, stdout);
        p += n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We compute the size of the initial segment not containing `:` or `\n`. If it's followed by a `:`, we skip over it and get the next segment that doesn't contain `\n`.

If it's followed by `\n`, we include the newline character in the segment. Then we just need to output the current segment and update `p` to continue processing the rest of the string in the same way.

We stop when `*p` is `'\0'`, i.e. when the end of the string is reached.

Comment: @Stargateur I don't understand that comment. Your suggested replacement still outputs `\n`.

Comment: That I wanted to say is that your example is not really easy to understand, the OP probably wants the token to be a "separate string". Here you print it without removing the original `'\n'` of the string. Maybe this will be better to do this for example of course http://rextester.com/BLS46506. But anyway, never mind, forget it.