# 2 variables and 1 string in one text

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40KML.png)

hello everyone ! i'm trying to make a robot where i can input the angle and distance from my phone ... so i used kodular ( like appinventor ) so my problem is i can't mix variables with string in kodular so i wanted to know is this format(photo) valid ? i want it to send smthg like : 90F150 (90 degree and 150 metre ) . the arduino will divide them into two different variables with the "F" ( special character ) have a good day everyone

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread on how to **split a string in C** (should work for the Arduino IDE) by a given character, which is known as a **delimiter**: [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)