# How to split line I read from file with delimiters and store them in each int variable in C

Tags: c, split, strsep

Hi I'm completely new to `C` and used to code in `python` so this has been bothering me for a while but I couldn't find an answer that I've been looking for so I decided to ask here.

I am reading a file called "input_date.txt" and will have to split it with delimiter `/` and store each part into different `int` variable.
Here's what I have so far:

```
int mm, dd, yy;

FILE* fp = fopen("input_date.txt", "r");
```

In the `input_date.txt` file there is only one line

```
5/17/07
```

I'll have to split them and store `5` in `mm`, `17` in `dd` and `07` in `yy` (all `int` variables). I kinda figured that I can use `strsep` but I'm still not too sure how to work with it (I barely started learning `C`) so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `strsep` really is a useful tool, here's a good link with an example https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1769 . Apart from that, you can also use `strtok`: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/

Comment: Research `fscanf`, `fgets`, `sscanf` and `strtok`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1, `strsep` is not part of the C standard library.

Comment: @jwdonahue I am aware, but I assumed @yerim2 can use `strsep` since they mentioned it in their post.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1, beginners present us with lots of [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). We should steer them towards the standards based solutions until they have achieved a minimum level of competence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

fscanf might do what you want?

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d/%d/%d",&mm,&dd,&yy) != 3) {
    /* Handle error */
    fputs ("error: invalid date format.\n", stderr);            
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` returns the number of successfully matched and assigned inputs. A non-zero return is not an error.

Comment: @jwdonahue.  Thanks, changed it to 3.  It throws an error if all three items were not assigned.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer seeing `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()`, but you get the nod for showing how to correctly ***check the return*** `:)` You may also want to show `/* handle error */` and the `printf()` is better `fputs ("error: invalid date format.\n", stderr);` so it is written to `stderr` and since there are no conversions involved, `printf()` can simply be replaced with `fputs()`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good suggestion.  I have changed the error handling accordingly.