# How can I get 4 integers from an IP address string?

Tags: c

I am trying to get 4 integers from an IP-address. For example, 12.34.56.78. A = 12, b = 34, c = 56, and d = 78. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
        
int main()
{
    char ADDRESS[100];
        
    printf("Enter IP: ");
    scanf("%s", ADDRESS);
    return 0;
}
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: What should happen if someone enters an IPv6 address?

Comment: read about `strtok()`.

Comment: `ADDRESS` isn't a preprocessor macro, so it should not be in all-caps.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c - I found this by doing a simple googl search for "c split string" - sou would it have for you …

Comment: Why would you want 4 integers from an IP-address? Why not just parse it into a `struct in_addr`? If you think an IP address consists of 4 integers, you don't understand network addressing.

Comment: @Cheatah Ridiculous comment -- an IPv4 address can be represented as 4 8-bit integers.  And perhaps they're not using POSIX networking .

Comment: It can also be represented as 8 hexadecimal characters, as a barcode or as a drawing of a moose. That does not mean it is convenient to use such representation format in memory. It will likely result in inconvenient and/or unnecessary stuff. It's almost always better to just treat it as a 32-bit object.

Answer (score 5):

try to use good old `sscanf()`.

```
int A, B, C, D;
sscanf(ADDRESS, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &A, &B, &C, &D);
```

It may be a good idea to check if `sscanf()` returned 4 what indicates that all four numbers were correctly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

if you're asked to read it as a string at first , you need to add a condition that it exists 4 points in the string

```
do { 
count=0;
   for (i=0;i<strlen(address);i++) {
        if (address[i] == '.') 
         count++;
         }
 if (count > 4) {
       printf("Enter IP: ");
scanf("%s", ADDRESS); }
while (!(count <= 4));
```

secondly using [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) can make everything easy , you have to split your string with the `.` caracter  so it goes with something like this

```
char *tester;
int counter=0,a,b,c,d;
tester = strtok(address, ".");
while( tester != NULL ) {
  switch (counter)  {
   case 0:
   a=atoi(tester);
   counter++;
   break;
   case 1:
   b=atoi(tester);
   counter++;
   break;
   case 2 :
   c=atoi(tester);
   counter++;
   break;
   case 3:
   d=atoi(tester);
   counter++;
   break; }
  tester= strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```