# How to split a string and store in different variables of a structure?

Tags: c

I have a string `" IN1::1209 OUT1::677 CURR1::4 KWh1::3 "` so i need only the values and that values to be stored in a structure. basically what I mean is that ex: `IN::1209` here I want only `1209` value and that value to be stored in a structure variable.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`strstr`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) and [`strtol`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)  and maybe for [`strtok`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your structure definition, of your input (std int, string in a variable, commandline parameter...?) and of your attempts. Please explain where in the "reading and ignoring until desired part of the string" process you are actually stuck. Without that, it is not even clear what code would solve your problem and also many users here believe that without that information your question does not match [ask] and hence should not be answered - or kept.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c

Answer (score 0):

In C, the `strtok()` function is used to split a string into a series of tokens based on a particular delimiter. A token is a substring extracted from the original string.

The general syntax for the `strtok()` function is:

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
```

Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[50] = "Hello! We are learning about strtok";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(string, " ");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

ouput:

```
Hello!
 We
 are
 learning
 about
 strtok
```

[Refer this link for more.](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/splitting-a-string-using-strtok-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that receives by reference a string, which is the parameter you want to split (in my case was a key-value string) and another string, which is the delimiter parameter.

It returns the two (separated by `delimiter`) parts of the first string parameter (`line`) in a `std::pair`.

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> split_key_value_pair( const std::string & line, const std::string & delimiter ){
    
    std::size_t pos = line.find( delimiter );

    std::pair<std::string, std::string> key_value;
    key_value.first = line.substr(0, pos);
    key_value.second = line.substr(pos + delimiter.size());

    return key_value;
}
```

Basically, after splitting the text that you want by the delimiter parameter, you can get the part of importance, `first` or `second`.

**Example**

```
/*create input */
    std::string my_text = "IN::1209";
    std::string delimiter = "::";

    
/* call routine */
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> key_value = split_key_value_pair(my_text, delimiter);
    

/* print to screen the output */
    std::cout << key_value.first() << std::endl; //will print IN
    std::cout << key_value.second() << std::endl; //will print 1209
```

Comment: Definitelly will compile using C compiler

Comment: Need the Code in C language