# Extract some data from array

Tags: c

I can normally extract the data of array  as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    char *c = (str + 29);
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I have to extract data from the entire unsorted and n-sized array where `n` value may be more than 70 as like:

```
unsigned char buffer[n] = "00,00,00,11,30,45.00,a,1.1,b,d,16,ABC,98.0";
unsigned char buffer1[n] = "A,3,22,18,21,06,03,09,24,15,,,,,2.5,1.6,1.9*3E";
```

How can I extract some specific data like `45.00` from this unsorted array?

Comment: If you know that `45.00` is in the data, why do you need to extract it?  If you mean "how can I find out if `45.00` is in the data", then maybe `strstr()` is what you're after.  Do you have to worry about a comma before the string (to avoid picking up `"12.00,145.00,29.00"` or the comma after it (to avoid picking up `"12.00,45.00"`)?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The data inside the buffer is unknown, it is just an example of how the data are formatted. Yeah, all the data are separated by a comma. I want to extract some data from it.

Comment: Use `strchr()` to find `','` from `buffer[]`.

Comment: OK — so you need to find a string such as `45.00` surrounded by commas, or at the start of the string followed by a comma, at the end of the string preceded by a comma?  This avoids picking up `145.00`, or `45.001`. And you won't be trying to find strings that start or end with comments?  And you won't be wanting to find `45` even though `45.00` and `45` are the same mathematically (even though they're different strings).

Comment: yeah, I need to find a string such as 45.00 surrounded by commas, or at the start of the string followed by a comma, at the end of the string preceded by a comma or like the example I showed in ```buffer1``` where there may not be data inside comma or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `split()` method used in this suggestion was developed by **@hmjd** to answer the referenced post; *I have made arragments on the `split()` method that will not change the result.* The solution is accomplished in five steps marked in the source code:

1. Using the `split()` method, the character array is split into tokens according to the `','` character.
2. The total number of tokens is calculated to find the number of data in the field indicated by the `**tokens` pointer.
3. Tokens are printed for testing purposes.
4. The `getIndex()` method searches for a special character array among the tokens and returns the index if found.
5. The returned index and data are printed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

/* (1) Splits a string by separator character. */
char** split(char* a_str, const char a_delim);
/* (2) Returns the total number of parts. */
size_t getSize(char **tokens);
/* (3) Prints tokens. */
void print(char **tokens);
/* (4) Searches for a data in tokens and returns the index of the result. */
int getIndex(char **tokens, char *search, size_t size);

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[] = "00,00,00,11,30,45.00,a,1.1,b,d,16,ABC,98.0";
    char search[] = "45.00";
    char **tokens = split(buffer, ',');                             /* 1 */
    size_t size =  getSize(tokens);                                 /* 2 */
    print(tokens);                                                  /* 3 */
    size_t index = getIndex(tokens, search, size);                  /* 4 */
    
    if(index >= 0)
        printf("Index: %ld Result: %s", index, *(tokens + index));  /* 5 */
    return 0;
}

char** split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char* tmp = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);
    count++;
    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

int getIndex(char **tokens, char *search, size_t size)
{
    int index;
    if(tokens)
        for(index = 0 ; *(tokens + index) ; index++)
            if(strcmp(search, *(tokens + index)) == 0)
                return index;
    return -1;
}

void print(char **tokens)
{
    if (tokens)
        for (size_t index = 0; *(tokens + index); index++)
            printf("[%ld]: %s\t", index, *(tokens + index));
    printf("\n");
}

size_t getSize(char **tokens)
{
    size_t counter = 0;
    while(*(tokens + counter))
        ++counter;
    return counter;
}
```

---

This source code produces the following output:

```
[0]: 00 [1]: 00 [2]: 00 [3]: 11 [4]: 30 [5]: 45.00 [6]: a [7]: 1.1 [8]: b [9]: d [10]: 16 [11]: ABC [12]: 98.0
Index: 5 Result: 45.00
```

---

###### References

- [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9210560/15032688)