# Read specific amount of words

Tags: c

How can I store just a specific words from this file in C?

```
Vaclav van Bouse;m;1994/07/13;zilinsky;73.66;81.72;66.83;92.70;78.78;68.95
Pavel Skoda;m;1998/10/25;bratislavsky;87.84;76.95;97.76;65.86;76.69;81.83
Jan Eduard Hubka;m;1989/02/23;kosicky;95.85;85.75;75.80;95.83;78.77;93.95
Viktor Hollmann;m;1991/11/11;zilinsky;88.76;95.93;95.84;72.66;89.77;97.65
Kristina Kovacova-Kruta;f;1993/08/12;presovsky;91.65;65.76;84.96;77.69;79.75;83.76
Lucia Handzusova;f;1999/01/31;banskobystricky;95.86;87.87;70.29;83.66;72.18;66.37
Dominik Komar;m;1994/06/04;trnavsky;83.18;69.67;86.56;76.79;95.67;84.78
Anna Maria Kollarova;f;2001/09/30;nitriansky;95.39;77.87;83.59;80.57;75.58;85.59
Eva Meszarosova;f;1997/02/29;zilinsky;65.79;77.98;66.27;84.59;93.59;76.88
Martin Drab;m;1999/05/06;trnavsky;76.38;75.97;69.77;96.48;76.56;65.19
Dana Ivana Sanna-Smith;f;1995/12/06;bratislavsky;90.39;83.09;96.76;87.77;99.18;67.78
```

i want to store the name , gender , everything what is ending with ';' i want to store in to different string

Comment: Read each line with `fgets`, split with `strtok`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

Comment: @tomasbrezina You can use fgets and sscanf.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.