# Normalize whitespace with strtok in C

Tags: c, whitespace, strtok

I am trying to use strtok to normalize whitespace in a string after I have removed a substring. Sometimes when I remove a substring there will be 2 spaces between two words and I want to reduce that to 1, for example deleting the substring "rise and" from the string "the rise and fall of rome" leaves 2 spaces between the and fall.

This is what I have so far but I have no experience with strtok:

```
char *strdel(char *string, const char *substring) {
    int mainlen, sublen;

    // finds the first occurrence of the substring
    char *del_sub = strstr(string, substring);
    char *wspc, *df;

    while (del_sub != NULL) {
        // finds length of string from beginning of substring
        // found in main string
        mainlen = strlen(del_sub);

        // finds length of the substring
        sublen = strlen(substring);

        // removes the number of bytes needed after the
        // first instance of the substring
        memmove(del_sub, del_sub + sublen, strlen(del_sub));     

        wspc = strtok(string, "  ");

        while ((df = strtok(NULL, "  ")) != NULL) {
            strcat(string, df);
            memset(df, 0, strlen(df));
        }

        // continues to search for another occurrence of the
        // substring until it equals NULL
        del_sub = strstr(string, substring);
    }

    return(string);
}
```

Comment: You've done a good job of providing a brief code sample (though note that it's ideal if you can limit the column width as well as the number of lines; I did that).  And you've defined your goal clearly.  But what you haven't made clear is what the "sticking point" is that you hit.  What line confused you?  When stepping in the debugger on simple examples...even as simple as removing `a` from `(space)a(space)`, where is your block?  It's better to show evidence of an attempt at debugging vs. "debug my code" and explain what specific thing you don't understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463664/971127

Comment: From wspc = strtok... to the while loop with(df = strtok... is my attempt at finding and deleting white space when there is more than 1 space in between letters and that is what I am having a problem with. I can remove the substring fine, but I am struggling putting together an algorithm for finding double spaces and then only deleting one of them.

Comment: Also, I tried using isspace(), which I think can be done as well, but I couldn't nail down an algorithm for that either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16790227/971127

Comment: Thanks for posting that twice because I didn't see it the first time, and also I am clearly not good enough at searching for help on my own

Comment: I would suggest to use strtok i.e. string tokenizer then combine and makeup string whatever you need by concatenating string. just another work around.